# qTip2 and Drupal 6 troubleshooting

Tags: 6, javascript

I am currently trying to implement a tooltip using the jQuery extension, qTip2. I have installed both of the files included in the extension (jquery.qtip.min.js and jquery.qtip.js in my /theme/js/ location, and their appropriate CSS sheets in /theme/css) and declared them in my theme's .info.

At the moment, I'm trying to write a function that displays the tooltip "Hello World" whenever someone hovers over an element of with the attribute #T6roll. I have the following as a script in my /sites/js/ location:

```
Drupal.behaviors.magds = function (context) {
  // Sounds, if using class "sound", these "#T1roll, #T2roll, #T3roll, #T4roll" can be removed, ul.dropdown li a, 
  $('ul.links li a, .sound, #T1roll, #T2roll, #T3roll, #T4roll').mouseover(function(){$.fn.soundPlay({url:Drupal.settings.magds.themeAbsolute+'flash/mouseover.wav',playerId:'embed_player',command:'play'});$("#sound").html("mouseover.wav");}).mouseout(function(){$.fn.soundPlay({playerId:'embed_player',command:'stop'});});

  // IE helpers
  if ($.browser.msie && ($.browser.version < 8)) {
    $('#main-menu li').hover(function() {
      $(this).addClass('hover');
      }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
  };
};

/* 
 * implements jquery.qTip.js
 */

 (function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a#T6roll).qtip({
            content: 'Hello World!',
            position: { target: 'mouse'}
        });
    });
 })(jQuery);
```

However, the site does not seem to be executing this. Is there any ideas as to what might be the cause of this? At first, I thought that it might be the qtip syntax, but I kept it as simple as can be to debug and it's not functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, it turns out that there is active development being done in the jQuery_Update module. Specifically, you may reference [this post](http://drupal.org/node/1067290#comment-5340730) .

The issue with the jQuery_Update module is that it would only update your Drupal 6 jQuery install to v. 1.3.0. With the patch that is applied in the aforementioned post, you are able to update all the way to jQuery 1.7.

An alternative to this solution would have been to load jQuery from another location and use the noConflict() function. [Drupal has some excellent documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1058168) regarding this.